# Run an Excel macro from a VB Script, but don't prompt VBA runtime errors

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'd like to run an Excel macro from within a VB script, but without VBA ever giving a runtime error prompt, even if the the macro has an uncaught runtime error.

Ideally I want to capture the actual runtime error message, but I'd be happy with just being able to resume the script without interacting with a dialog.

Here's a minimal example of what I'm talking about.

test.vbs:

```
Option Explicit 

Dim Excel: set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim wb: set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\test.xls")

On Error Resume Next
Excel.run "Hello"
On Error Goto 0

wb.Close
Excel.Quit
```

Within module1 of an Excel spreadsheet named test.xls:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Hello()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1 / 0 ' Just causing an error for this example's purposes
End Sub
```

For a short explanation as to the motivation behind this question. This is an automation task, except I can't change the code of the macro that needs to be automated, and so I can't control whether the macro I call is going to have an uncaught runtime error or not.

There are many, many questions on Stackoverflow asking about running Excel macros using VB scripts, but I haven't been able to find any that addresses being able to suppress VBA runtime error prompts.

Comment: Are you looking for `Excel.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: That's a good question. I forgot to mention: I tried that, but it didn't work. I also tried ``.Interactive = false`` and a few others.

Answer (score 1):

Please Inlcude On Error Resume Next after Sub rountine

Option Explicit

```
Sub Hello()
On Error Resume Next
' Please include the error statement after sub routine.
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1 / 0 ' Just causing an error for this example's purposes
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't change the code of the subroutine. The subroutines I'm actually trying to run are many, many thousands of lines of spaghetti code that I didn't write and are subject to change at any time by several users. I can't rely on runtime errors all being caught. The aim of the question is to prevent the VB script from halting when such an error comes up.

Comment: I think it is not possible. You are accessing macros from VB scripts. You have access to VB Scripts however, you dont have access to Macros. the pop events or dialog boxes etc are part of macros. Since VB Scripts cant modify the macros , flow control will be unchanged. So i think it is not possible to modify or change the flow control in macros from VB Scripts

Comment: The Excel.Application object can control some aspects of the Excel environment though. As by Ansgar above in a comment above, `Excel.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Excel.Interactive = False` can disable certain dialogs from happening in the Excel environment. I was hoping there was some other property I could set or some function I could call that would change how Excel handles VBA runtime errors specifically. Or if that's actually impossible, a link to some authoritative answer saying so.